# C++ Shallow and deep copying - reflecting changes in the num_items of a vector

Tags: c++, vector, copy, deep-copy, shallow-copy

I'm currently undertaking a C++ course at university. I understand the general concept of shallow and deep copying using vectors however there's an example in my textbook that has me confused.

Please assume that it is a poorly implemented vector with no copy constructor defined so that it only performs a shallow copy of the data.

I understand what's happening in the first part

> In the statement
>
> > `vector<int> v2(v1);`
>
> vector `v1` is passed as a const reference argument to the vector copy
>   constructor, so `v1` can’t be changed, and the variable `v2` is then
>   initialized to a copy of the vector `v1`. Each data field will be
>   copied, and any changes made later to `v2` should not affect `v1`. When
>   the value in `v1.the_data` is copied over, both `v1.the_data` and
>   `v2.the_data` will point to the same array
>
> Because `v1.the_data` and `v2.the_data` point to the same object, the
>   statement
>
> ```
> v1[2] = 10;
> ```
>
> also changes `v2[2]`. For this reason, `v2` is considered a shallow copy
>   of `v1`.

However I'm struggling to understand this part. I'm not quite sure why `v2.num_items` won't also change in a shallow copy.

> The statement
>
> ```
> v1.push_back(20);
> ```
>
> will insert `20` into `v1[5]` and will change `v1.num_items` to 6, but will
>   not change `v2.num_items`.

My current thoughts on it are that `v1.the_data` and `v2.the_data` are pointing to the same place in memory therefore they 'share' the same vector so that when 20 is added to the end of it both of the vectors should gain an additional integer.

I would greatly appreciate assistance in understanding why the number of items won't change for `v2` when `v1` is modified.

Comment: In the "quoted part" from your textbook ?!

Comment: Unless the quoted part describes the behavior of an incorrectly implemented vector, it is a piece of trash.

Comment: It's from a handout provided by my instructor. I think it's meant to be an incorrectly implemented vector. I'll edit my post to make this clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming we are talking about the standard `std::vector` :

When you copy the vector in this statement :

```
vector<int> v2(v1);
```

v2 is built by copying each element of v1. v1 and v2 do not share any of their memory.

This part :

> both v1.the_data and v2.the_data will point to the same array
>
> Because v1.the_data and v2.the_data point to the same object,

Is wrong.

You can convince yourself by comparing the underlying arrays addresses of each of your vectors with the `data()` [member function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data).

**EDIT :**

Assuming you are crazy enough to not use `std::vector` and use an implementation that would "share" its back end array when copied (I wont talk about the issues with this design : who owns the array ? who `delete[]` it ?)

The issue raised by your teacher is that when `v1` is modified (e.g. an element is added), `v2` does not know about it, and has an unchanged size.

Any `push_back` (or the likes) made to one vector should be observed by every other owner of the array, to properly reflect the size of the array.

Either :

1) you implement some kind of observer pattern to have each vector aware of any modification (and it is more difficult than it sounds)

2) you use tricks to store the length in the backend array itself.

You would run into similar issues to invalid every iterators when the "shared" array is modified through one of the vectors references... A nightmare ! There are good reasons why the STL containers were *all* designed to managed their own memory, hence always providing deep copy semantics.

Comment: Edited my question with the assumption that it isn't std::vector.

If it was an implementation of std::vector I'm assuming that it would perform a deep copy.

Answer (score 2):

Is your textbook talking about `std::vector` from the standard library? If so, it is wrong. `vector<int> v2(v1);` *copy constructs* `v2` from `v1`. This is a deep copy, the two containers don't share storage and are completely separate.

If, instead, this is a badly implemented `vector` class and the containers share storage then changing an **existing** element in one will be reflected in the other. An operation like `push_back` that changed one container's `num_items` but not the other's would cause them to disagree on their size.

Comment: Sorry, I should have added the assumption that it is not using the std::vector but a poor implementation of it.

Comment: @juleszero: Updated to reflect one of the problems with a poorly designed vector class.

Answer (score 2):

The statement seems to assume a particular implementation of
`vector` (which is not conform with `std::vector`).  Suppose,
for example, we have a very naïve implementation:

```
template <typename T>
class Vector
{
    T* myData;
    int mySize;
    int myCapacity;
public:
    void push_back( T const& newValue )
    {
        if ( mySize == myCapacity ) {
            //  Extend the capacity...
        }
        myData[mySize] = newValue;
        ++ mySize;
    }
    T& operator[]( int index )
    {
        return myData[index];
    }
};
```

If you don't have a copy constructor, when you copy the vector,
all three variables will end up the same: both vectors will have
a pointer to the same data, the same size and the same capacity.
But these are copies: when you use `[]`, you modify the memory
pointed to by `myData`, which is the same in both vectors; when
you do the `push_back` on `v1`, you update the *size* of `v1`,
in its local copy of the size.

Of course, this implementation is naïve in a lot of ways.
A good implementation of something like `std::vector` requires
a fair amount of thought, not just because if requires deep copy
semantics, but also for reasons of exception safety (the
constructor of `T` might throw), and to avoid imposing
unnecessary requirements (in particular, a default constructor).

Also, if I were trying to use a poorly implemented vector as an example of shallow copy, I wouldn't call it `vector`, since that immediately conjures up the image of `std::vector`, which shouldn't be poorly implemented (and isn't in the library implementations I know).

Answer (score 0):

The problem in understanding the statement in this question is whether when we have to consider vector as std::vector or as a theoretical implementation.  std::vector doesn't allow shallow copying and the reason is given in the statement: the invariants can't be respected because of this.

Now take the theoretical implementation with "the_data" and "num_items" members.  Here copying the vector should give a deep copy, but just copying "the_data" gives a shallow copy because only a pointer is copied.  This gives several issues: adapting the actual data in one vector will result in an inconsistent state in the other and memory management can't be done anymore.